# Is "during" or "while" is correct in the given sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> 1: Your level of hormones changes "while" travelling.
>   2: Your level of hormones changes "during" travelling.

I think that "during" would be right if travelling is used as a gerund in the second sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conjunction *while* doesn't work with nouns and noun phrases. Thus, locutions such as *while the house*, *while the pen* and *while your travels* can't stand on their own and don't really make any sense. You need something that's active—something that's doing something. That's why with the conjunction *while* you can either use the "ing" form of a verb (present participles place special stress on the process of doing something) or a clause consisting of a subject and a verb (a verb is a doing word):

> Your level of hormones changes **while travelling**.
>
> He visited the Louvre **while he was in Paris**.

With the preposition *during*, on the other hand, you can only use a noun or a noun phrase (something that's stationary):

> Your level of hormones changes **during travel**.
>
> It's very quiet here **during the night**.